# Assitant Hindi Issue in Google Nest Audio

Tags: google-smart-home

I am working on google actions in Hindi and English language. In English all utterances working fine on nest audio.

But Hindi Utterances are not working fine on nest audio.

Let's say.

In English : Turn On Bedroom A/C (Working)

In Hindi: बेडरूम को चालू करो (Working)

But  बेडरूम ऐसी को चालू करो (Not Working)

Nest Audio assistant does n't understand बेडरूम ऐसी only understand बेडरूम. But android phone assistant understand बेडरूम ऐसी. Can you please check this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a potential bug on the Assistant’s Natural Language Understanding engine. Can you please open up a ticket on the public issue tracker, include a video on both phone and display device cases (please try both writing and speaking on the phone) and provide your sync response as well.